# How to create a class and add fields dynamically in typescript?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a class in which I get options as an argument which is a JSON object, now I want to add the keys of this JSON object as properties to my existing class how to do this?
for example
I have a class

```
class user{
username: string,
password: string,
}
```

now my options object is as

```
{
"firstName":"string
}
```

so now I want to add this firstname property to my user class how to do it

Comment: Are you sure you want to add properties to your *class*? It would make more sense to add properties to *objects*.

Comment: How to do it in case of objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer but not recommend doing this.

Because adding arbitrary property to an object make the typescript compiler unable to check the potential mistakes for you.

```js
class user {
    username: string = ""
    password: string = ""
}

let option = {
    "firstName": "string"
}

let myuser = new user()

for (let k of Object.keys(option)) {
    (myuser as any)[k] = (option as any)[k]
}

console.log(myuser)
// user {username: "", password: "", firstName: "string"}
```

Comment: You can shorten the for loop to `Object.assign(myuser, option)`. This will also return the object myuser but with type `user & { firstName: string }`, allowing the compiler to keep track the extra properties.

Answer (score 4):

This, my friend. Is all you need https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

Class transformer can transform objects to classes with a given prototype and reverse! With Expose and Exclude decorators :D

```js
class TestClass {
  @Exclude()
  test: boolean = false;

  @Expose()
  showMe: boolean = true;
}
```

```js
const data = {test: true, showMe: false};

console.log(data.constructor.prototype); // Object

const result = plainToClass(TestClass, data);

console.log(result.constructor.prototype); // TestClass

const response = classToPlain(result); // {showMe: false}
```

But with nestjs! You should be able to do this anyway! Using metatypes :)

```js
@Controller()
export class TestController {
  @Post()
  test(
    @Body() test: TestClass,
 ): void {
   console.log(test); // should be instance of TestClass
 }
}
```

I could be wrong. You might have to use ValidationPipe or install class transformer to achieve this but always worked for me and never questioned it!

Comment: `@Body()` is not giving me an instance of a class. `console.log(test instanceof TestClass)` returns `false`.

Comment: @Marco I would double check that your version of nestjs is up to date and that you are using `class-transformer` and `class-validator`

Comment: Our installation of nestjs was more than 6 monthes old. We updated nestjs to version 7.6.x. and both class-validator and class-transformer are installed. But I need to manually call `plainToClass()`. I might have missed something...

Comment: Late to the party, but I'd double check your `main.ts` (or wherever your nestjs `bootstrap()` is), and ensure you have a global (or controller) validation pipe, containing config like `{ transform: true, forbidNonWhitelisted: true }` (with `forbid*` being optional). Personally I feel nestjs could be even more opinionated by having that as a default. If you've double checked that, maybe raise a q.